# How do I unit test that a method is called with the correct "this"?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Recently I ran into a bug where `someFunction` was being called with the incorrect context.

```
var args = [/* any number of values here */];
var someFunction = function(filter) {
    filter.set.apply(filter, args)
};
```

Specifically, `filter.set` was called with a different context instead of `filter`. Is there a way to test that `filter.set` is being called with the context set as `filter` with Jasmine?

Comment: Make a mock context.

Comment: I don't think that would solve it. filter is already a mock object and I am asserting that set is called with args. I also want to assert that filter.set is being called with "this" set to filter, as opposed to "this" which might point to something else.

Comment: You mean "with the correct *this*".

Comment: I've heard it phrased both ways but maybe saying "with the correct this" is clearer.